# Unknown number of regex replacements, how?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I need to change a large number of URIs in the following way:

1. substitute `%20` separators with dashes `-`,
2. substitute the old root with a new domain.

Examples:

```
/old_root/first/second.html -> http://new_domain.com/first/second
/old_root/first/second%20third.html -> http://new_domain.com/first/second-third
/old_root/first/second%20third%20fourth.html -> http://new_domain.com/first/second-third-fourth
```

The best I came up with using regex is to write as many pattern-replacement rules as the maximum number of `%20` separators that can occur in my URIs:

```
old_root/(.*?)/(.*?)\.html -> http://new_domain.com/$1/$2
old_root/(.*?)/(.*?)%20(.*?)\.html -> http://new_domain.com/$1/$2-$3
old_root/(.*?)/(.*?)%20(.*?)%20(.*?)\.html -> http://new_domain.com/$1/$2-$3-$4
```

My question is: **is it possible to obtain the same result using a single regular expression rule?**

I thought I could use a two-step approach: first change all `%20` separators to `-` and then use the rule `old_root/(.*?)/(.*?)\.html -> http://new_domain.com/$1/$2/`. However, I need to apply this rule in a `.htaccess` file as a `RedirectMatch` directive and, as far as I know, it is not possible to use two successive rules for the same redirect directive.

Comment: Can't there be an intermediate step in htaccess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Apache recursively applies all regex rules until they stop matching. Therefore, I am allowed to write two rules rather than one to solve my problem.

The following rules do what I was looking for, and more; I have tested them on my local Apache server and they work fine. Note that for them to work, you need to first turn on the rewrite engine by prepending

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
```

in the local `.htaccess` file or in the global `httpd.conf` file.

**Replace all spaces with hyphens**

Replace both literal spaces and `%20` with hyphens:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%20)(.+)$ /$1-$3 [R=301,NE,L]
```

**Replace all apostrophes with hyphens**

Replace all literal apostrophes and `%60` with hyphens:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)('|`|%60)(.+)$ /$1-$3 [R=301,NE,L]
```

**Delete the trailing `.html` extension**

```
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

**Convert the last field in the URL to lower case**

Convert the last field in the URL to lower case and prepend the new domain:

```
RewriteRule /whatever/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*) http://new.domain.com/$1/$2/${lc:$3} [R=301,L]
```

***Important:*** The lowercase conversion will only work if you include the following lines at the end of the Apache configuration file `httpd.conf`, which is usually located in the `etc` directory on the server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

A last note: I recommend prepending each rule with a `RewriteCond` directive to restrict the field of application of the rule. For example, to apply the space-to-hyphens rule only to those URI that match a certain regex, you should write the following in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} regex_for_URIs
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%20)(.+)$ /$1-$3 [R=301,NE,L]
```

where `regex_for_URIs` is the regular expression that the URI must match in order for the next `RewriteRule` to be applied; it can also be a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you were almost done.

**Problems**

- Don't return `"%20"` - We'll Use them as "delimiter" of parts of the path
- Add condition on third & fourth group (because you might pass short URL i.e. your examples)

**Solution**

```
\/old_root\/(.*?)\/(\w*)(?:%20)?(\w*)?(?:%20)?(\w*)?\.html
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC7yU9/2)

**Explanation**

- `(?:%20)?` means `"%20"` is non catching group that can occurs 0 or 1 time.
- Same logic applyies on possible 3rd & 4th part.

Comment: THANK YOU for your answer! Your pattern matches my URLs very well, as long as I include enough repetitions of `(?:%20)?(\w*)?`. However, I am having issues with the replacement part of the regex. I tried with `http://new_domain.com/$1/$2-$3-$4-$5` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC7yU9/5)), but it results in extra dash characters unless the optional pattern `(\w*)?` fires exactly four times. I would need a condition whereby the dash is included ONLY if the next pattern fires. Is there a way to do so?
By the way, thanks for showing me [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), it is a life saver!

Comment: Please copy over your regex from the testing site, in case it goes down (or messes up the database, which it did a few months ago...)

Comment: Btw, this is a wrong solution to the problem. Your solution fails to account for the actual number of `%20` in the URL to replace.

Comment: I've figured out something - First : it is impossible to replace BOTH : subsitute %20 & remove old_root. COz First operation requires the old string intact EXCEPT all %20 & second operation modify the old string. How about using RewriteCond RewriteRule x3 - Because u could match every categories apart ? First excluding %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} would remove 1 operation - That would let you 3 patterns to match who looks like : first/second.html - second%20third.html - first/second%20third%20fourth.html. U'll able to know how many %20 to remove if you know which pattern you're facing

Comment: @Falt4rm, Thanks for you comment! I ended up using a solution that is not too different from what you are proposing, but works for an arbitrary number of `%20`. I have added this solution above as an answer.

Comment: Well that's good to hear you manage to create a solution on your own.